# Trigger that box whith a button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Is it possible to trigger this rotate function with a click on a button? with `:active` it's possible to rotate it by clicking on the box. But you will need to keep the button pressed; is it possible to have some kind of toggle function on :active?

Is there any JavaScript to make a box flip?

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.flip-box {
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #f1f1f1;
  perspective: 1000px;
}

.flip-box-inner {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  transition: transform 0.8s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.flip-box:hover .flip-box-inner {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.flip-box-front,
.flip-box-back {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.flip-box-front {
  background-color: #bbb;
  color: black;
}

.flip-box-back {
  background-color: dodgerblue;
  color: white;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

```html
<h1>3D Flip Box (Horizontal)</h1>
<h3>Hover over the box below:</h3>

<div class="flip-box">
  <div class="flip-box-inner">
    <div class="flip-box-front">
      <h2>Front Side</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="flip-box-back">
      <h2>Back Side</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you want it to continue to flip/rotate from front to back? Do you want the card to stay in the 'flipped' position, so the back side stays visible? Something else?

Comment: ooh sry... No i want it to rotate 180 degand stop untill i activate it again.

Answer (score 1):

One approach is as below, with comments in the code to explain what's going on:

```js
// here we use document.querySelector() to retrieve the first <button> element
// in the document; we then use EventTarget.addEventListener() to bind the
// anonymous Arrow function as the event-handler for the 'click' event:
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', (e)=>{
  // the Event Object ('e') is passed to the function body, we retrieve
  // the element to which the function was bound (Event.currentTarget)
  // and from there we use Element.closest() to find the closest '.card-wrap'
  // element:
  e.currentTarget.closest('.card-wrap')
    // from there we use Element.querySelector() to find the first (if any)
    // flip-box element within that ancestor:
    .querySelector('.flip-box')
    // and use the Element.classList API to toggle the 'active' class
    // on that 'flip-box' element:
    .classList.toggle('active');
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.flip-box {
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #f1f1f1;
  perspective: 1000px;
}

.flip-box-inner {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  transition: transform 0.8s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.flip-box:hover .flip-box-inner,
/* added another selector, so that the
   .flip-box-inner element within
   .flip-box.active also rotates (is
   rotated): */
.flip-box.active .flip-box-inner {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.flip-box-front,
.flip-box-back {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.flip-box-front {
  background-color: #bbb;
  color: black;
}

.flip-box-back {
  background-color: dodgerblue;
  color: white;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

```html
<h1>3D Flip Box (Horizontal)</h1>
<h3>Hover over the box, or click the button, below:</h3>

<!-- creating a wrapper element for each 'card' or 'flip-box' in order
     to query the DOM more easily to find the relevant .flip-box from
     a clicked <button>: -->
<div class="card-wrap">
  <!-- insert a <button> with which the user can interact: -->
  <button type="button">Toggle the card</button>
  <div class="flip-box">
    <div class="flip-box-inner">
      <div class="flip-box-front">
        <h2>Front Side</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="flip-box-back">
        <h2>Back Side</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/mvg671kL/).

References:

- HTML:

  - [`<button>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button).
- JavaScript:

  - [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).
  - [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).
  - [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).
  - [`Element.classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList).
  - [`Element.closest()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest).
  - [`Element.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector).
  - [`Element.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll).
  - [`Event`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event).
  - [`EventTarget.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).

Comment: Thank you I realy appreciate you taking time to explain the funktions. is it possible to do it whith Jquery so I can fadeIn/fadeOut new//old content aswell?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done without Javascript:

```css
body {
     font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
 .flip-box {
     background-color: transparent;
     width: 300px;
     height: 200px;
     border: 1px solid #f1f1f1;
     perspective: 1000px;
}
 .flip-box-inner {
     position: relative;
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
     text-align: center;
     transition: transform 0.8s;
     transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
 .check:checked ~ .flip-box .flip-box-inner {
     transform: rotateY(180deg);
     background-color: black;
}
 .flip-box-front, .flip-box-back {
     position: absolute;
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
     -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
     backface-visibility: hidden;
}
 .flip-box-front {
     background-color: #bbb;
     color: black;
}
 .flip-box-back {
     background-color: dodgerblue;
     color: white;
     transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

/* Here is the code I added */
 a.click-button {
     background: steelblue;
     padding: 5px;
     border-radius: 5px;
     color: white;
     margin-bottom: 20px;
     display: inline-block;
}
 input[type="checkbox" i] {
     display: none;
}
```

```html
   <h1>3D Flip Box (Horizontal)</h1>
   <h3>Hover over the box below:</h3>
   
   <!-- add a checkbox -->
   <input type="checkbox" class="check" id="checked">
   <label class="menu-btn" for="checked">
   <a class="click-button">click here</a>
   </label>
   
   
   <div class="flip-box">
      <div class="flip-box-inner">
         <div class="flip-box-front">
            <h2>Front Side</h2>
         </div>
         <div class="flip-box-back">
            <h2>Back Side</h2>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: Awsome... Im sory about my spelling. English aint my first language and im dyslektik. But thanks ealy thanks this whith the button is 100% what im after.

Comment: If I use Jquery on that button and the fadeOut funktion. It shouled be possible to show new content for every toggle.. right?

Comment: @HenrikF  Even for that, you don't need any JS or JQuery. You can toggle the content using the visibility to hide and show elements... and of course you can animate the button and content with css only

Answer (score 0):

As long as you don't care about IE, `classList` is a well-supported option.

In your CSS file, change the following:

```
/* old: */
.flip-box:hover .flip-box-inner {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

/* new: */
.toggle .flip-box-inner {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

Then create a JavaScript file and add the following to it.

```
document
  .getElementsByClassName('flip-box')[0]
  .addEventListener('click', function () {
    this.classList.toggle('toggle');
  });
```

Then add the following `<script>` element to your html file.

```
<script src="<your JavaScript file name>.js"></script>
```

Here is the full code snippet:

```js
document
  .getElementsByClassName('flip-box')[0]
  .addEventListener('click', function () {
    this.classList.toggle('toggle');
  });
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.flip-box {
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #f1f1f1;
  perspective: 1000px;
}

.flip-box-inner {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  transition: transform 0.8s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.toggle .flip-box-inner {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.flip-box-front,
.flip-box-back {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.flip-box-front {
  background-color: #bbb;
  color: black;
}

.flip-box-back {
  background-color: dodgerblue;
  color: white;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

```html
<h1>3D Flip Box (Horizontal)</h1>
<h3>Hover over the box below:</h3>

<div class="flip-box">
  <div class="flip-box-inner">
    <div class="flip-box-front">
      <h2>Front Side</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="flip-box-back">
      <h2>Back Side</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: That definately does.... thanks.. It realy is amazing. Ive never entered any Community like this. Every one is super kind. Mostley today in other Communitys they look down and laughs at noobs like me =)

 Im sory about my spelling. English aint my first language and im dyslektik.

Comment: we all start somewhere. Just focus on improving and surrounding yourself with positive people and environments, and you'll do just fine. glad to help and wish you the best.

Answer (score 0):

- define a generic `.flip` class that does a 180deg turn of any element it is assigned to with `transform: rotateY(180deg)`.
- add an original state `transform: rotateY(0deg)` to the class to be flipped (here `.flip-box-inner` showing the 'front').
- Assign a Javascript *click event listener* to the parent to be clicked (here `.flip-box`).
- have JS toggle the generic `.flip` class on/off.

**UPDATE** reply after OP comment

I replaced the snippet Javscript with jQuery syntax doing the same as the initial vanilla Javascript.

```js
/*
   jQuery alternative
*/
$('.flip-box').on('click', function() {
    $('.flip-box-inner').toggleClass('flip');
});

/* DISABLED ORIGINAL JAVASCRIPT, no jQuery
// Reference to elements concerned
// This can be any parent/child combination
const el1 = document.querySelector(".flip-box");       // parent to be clicked
const el2 = document.querySelector(".flip-box-inner"); // child to be flipped

// Attach listener to parent, toggle child flip
el1.addEventListener('click', () => { el2.classList.toggle('flip') });
*/
```

```css
body {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.flip-box {
    background-color: transparent;
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid #f1f1f1;
    perspective: 1000px;
}

.flip-box-inner {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    transition: transform 0.8s;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;

    /* ADDED, original state */
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
}

/* CHANGED from '.flip-box:hover .flip-box-inner' to */
.flip { transform: rotateY(180deg) }
/* When toggled 'off' in JS '.flip-box-inner'
   will revert back to original state */

.flip-box-front,
.flip-box-back {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.flip-box-front {
    background-color: #bbb;
    color: black;
}

.flip-box-back {
    background-color: dodgerblue;
    color: white;
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1>3D Flip Box (Horizontal)</h1>
<h3>Hover over the box below:</h3>

<div class="flip-box">
    <div class="flip-box-inner">
        <div class="flip-box-front">
            <h2>Front Side</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="flip-box-back">
            <h2>Back Side</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Tank you. Im making my first website and I am learning as I go along. I find javascript hard to figur  out. I realy like Jquery more. Is it possible to Swith the Javascript to Jquery?